Optimization of a Graph $f(x)$ to a Point
Suppose you have the function, say $f(x)=x^2+1$. You want to find the point on the graph that is closest to $(4,2)$. Minimizing the distance formula $\sqrt{(x-5)^2+((x^2+1)-2)^2}$. Scenarios tell you to only take the derivative of the radicand.
Does this generalize to all cases? What if the point that was minimized was $(2,4)$ and the distance can be clearly seen as less than $1$.
This previous assumption is made thinking $x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ give the same minimum value. I believe that if the distance between the point and $(c,f(c))$ is less than one, this assumption cannot be made because the minimum value would not be the same. Shouldn't the distance be greater and therefore the minimum value would be different?

Let $Q(x)\ge 0$ be the radicand, then, for all $x$ and $x'$,
\begin{equation}
Q(x)\le Q(x') \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{Q(x)}\le \sqrt{Q(x')}
\end{equation}
This proves that $Q(x)$ and $\sqrt{Q(x)}$ reach their minimum at the same points, which of course does not mean that they have the same minimum value.

Define $t$ to be the radicand.
The function $f(t)=\sqrt t$ has a derivative $$\frac d{dx} \sqrt t=\frac1{2\sqrt t}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}$$ and to optimize $f(t)$ on $x$ we must zero the derivative $\dfrac{d}{dx}\sqrt t$.
Observe that $\dfrac{dt}{dx}=0\iff \dfrac d{dx} \sqrt t=0$.  This shows that it suffices to zero the radicand if we wish to zero the derivative.
